# How to persist java.util.Properties using XML entity mappings (orm.xml)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have an entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // some fields such as Long, String etc.

  private java.util.Properties properties;

  // getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString ...
}
```

And XML entity mappings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
      <access>FIELD</access>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
  </persistence-unit-metadata>

  <entity class="com.package.of.my.MyEntity">
    <table name="my_entity">
      <unique-constraint name="uniquefield">
        <column-name>uniquefield</column-name>
      </unique-constraint>
    </table>

    <!-- some named queries -->

    <attributes>
      <id name="id"><generated-value/></id>

      <!-- some <basic name="..."> columns -->

      <!-- What to put here for mapping the properties field? -->

      <!-- other mappings (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many) -->
    </attributes>
  </entity>

  <!-- other entity mappings -->
</entity-mappings>
```

How can I ideally map the `java.util.Properties` object?

Using `<basic name="properties"/>` results in an error: Attribute cannot be resolved. However, it DOES add a BLOB column to the database table.

`Properties` works with `String` keys and values, but actually extends `Hashtable<Object,Object>` (which implements `Map<Object,Object>`). That looks like a one-to-many. But `Object` is not an entity so that doesn't work either.